# Create .htaccess Rewrite rule same as wordpress

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I am Creating Rewrite Rule in .htaccess

I have some issue i am creating Rule like wordpress but i didnt get correctly

The Rule which i am writing is below

```
`RewriteRule projectDir/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)$ index.php?module=$1&action=$2&id=$3`
```

In this ReFacta is my Project Directory

The Url Which i want it same as like below

```
`http://localhost/projectDir/user/edit/5`
```

Any idea Friends ?

Comment: are you getting any error?

Comment: No i didnt get any error just 404 Not Found

Comment: Wordpress never alters it's `.htaccess` directives - it simply forwards any request that doesn't exist to index.php - which makes things a hell of a lot easier because then you can manage your pages and redirects etc. in PHP by taking a look at `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`.

Comment: i dont want to alert wordpress `.htaccess` i want to create rewrite rule like guven up

Comment: @MaddyVora check my answer it will help you

Answer (score 4):

You are nearly correct. what is wrong in your code, you don't have specified `RewriteBase`

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /projectDir
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/(.*)$ /index.php?module=$1&action=$2&id=$3 [L]
```

Comment: Not Working Bro. Still Same issue

Comment: I am Getting Error like this

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator, admin@localhost and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

Comment: @MaddyVora you need to change some settings in your httpd.conf file

Comment: its `AllowOverride all` on conf file

Comment: I got the answer the issue is mod_rewrite is desabled in httpd.conf file

Comment: ya i used that code but need to some change

`RewriteRule (.*)/(.*)/(.*)$ index.php?module=$1&action=$2&id=$3 [L]`

Comment: you have to use this code `RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/(.*)$ index.php?module=$1&action=$2&id=$3 [L]`